# Golang TCP client server implementation

Tags: go

I have a question on how to handle disconnects on a golang TCP client

I have the below function which is in a continuous loop and reconnects on every loop

```
func (t *TcpConnector) Connect() {
    for {

        if t.reconnectAttempt > t.reconnectMaxRetries {
            t.onNoReconnect(t.reconnectAttempt)
            return
        }

        if t.reconnectAttempt > 0 {
            t.onReconnect()
        }

        c, err := net.Dial("tcp", t.Url)

        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Connection to tcp server failed with error : %+v", err)

            if t.autoReconnect {
                t.reconnectAttempt++
                continue
            }

            return
        }

        t.Log.Infof("Connection established @ %s", time.Now())
        t.Conn = c

        defer t.Conn.Close()

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        wg.Add(1)

        go t.SendHeartbeat()
        go t.Write(&wg)
        go t.RecieveResponse()

        err = t.SendLoginPacket()

        if err != nil {
            appsetup.MOSLTcpServerLoginFailureAlert(t.AppState, err)
            continue
        }

        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

I block this loop with `var wg sync.WaitGroup` and will on continue once all the waitgroups complete.

The SendHeartbeat writes a packet every 30 seconds to the TCP server

```
func (t *TcpConnector) SendHeartbeat() {

    ticker := time.NewTicker(30 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for x := range ticker.C {
        messageHeader, err := getMessageHeaderInBytes(129, 0, 0, t.AppState.Config.Username)
        if err != nil {
            t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Error Converting heartbeat request data to bytes: %+v, with seconds: %s", err, x)
            return
        }
        t.DataChannel <- messageHeader
    }
}
```

This sends byte data over on a channel and is recieved by the `t.Write()`
function. There are many other functions which write to this channel which is taken over by the `Write()` function

```
func (t *TcpConnector) Write(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-t.DataChannel:
            _, err := t.Conn.Write(data)
            if err != nil {
                t.AppState.Log.Errorf("Error Sending byte data to TCP server: %+v", err)
                t.Conn.Close()
                wg.Done()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see , what i do here is that on error - i return `wg.done` which unblocks the `Connect()` function and this proceeds with reconnecting to the server.

Sometimes , the TCP socket gets closed and the Write function errors out. But since there are multiple goroutines invoking the `Write()` function on a parallel - all of them error out and i get the below error

```
panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter
```

I understand this is caused because the `Write()` function calls `Wg.Done()` multiple times on erroring out (because multiple goroutines invoke it)

Is there a better way i can handle this?

Comment: This is a misuse of `WaitGroup`. `Add` and `Done` should each be called *exactly once per goroutine* managed by the `WaitGroup`. Trying to manage any other logical construct, like connections or writes, will lead to trouble - it's for managing *goroutines*.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything to stop the loop in `TCPConnector.Write` from exiting, so it could easily call `wg.Done` multiple times, with no matching `wg.Add` call.

Comment: How would one tackle this issue ? Are there better approaches? Any resources i can look at? I'm very new to go and still finding my way about

Comment: @JamesHenstridge - If I return from the function on error (TCPConnector.Write) - the  process no longer panics. But i'm worried if this is bad practice , basically the heartbeat function would still be sending byte date over the channel but there is no corresponding write function that reads from the channel. But if this is the case , why is my process not crashing?